# High dimensional explanatory variable

Tags: feature-selection, high-dimensional

I have a data set of 22 observations and 6931 variables. 
Data belongs to two classes, 0 and 1.

I would like to know which features are important for each class (species) and which one contribute the most to class difference.

In other words, which features do I have to change if I want my observation to "move" from one class to another?

Thank you so much :)

[image: X are my observations, i have 22 of them; AAR,AAQ,... are variables; i have 6931 different combinations of triplets]

Comment: Do you mean 22 variables and 6931 observations? If no, then you have data inadequacy problem. Can you please show your data here?

Comment: No, I have 22 variables (22 different bacteria, belonging to two different species (Escherichia & Lactobaccilus)), each bacteria is represented by triplets of aminoacids (in this case, 6931 variables).

Comment: Again you are confusing in your comment.. 22 variables & 6931 variables..

Comment: oh, sorry, it was correct in the first place; 22 observationa and 6931 variables